# DropDownList Value not empty

Tags: asp.net, .net, drop-down-menu, webforms, html-select

I'm having an weird problem, i've copied and pasted some code, but this one works fine at one view and doesn't works at another one.

My problem is the dropDownList ("Destino" or "Origem") when got no value property val ("") have the text property val ("Selecione um tipo"), but after the first "SelectIndexChange" Event trigger, this dropDownList got the val ("Selecione um tipo") for text and value property.

Thats my code:

```
    protected void ddlTipoUADestinoSrc_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<UnidadeArmazenamento> uas = new UnidadeArmazenamentoBO().GetAllUnidadesArmazenamentoByUnidade(LoggedUser.UnidadeActiva.IDUNIDADE, false);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlTipoUADestinoSrc.SelectedValue))
        {
            if (ddlTipoUADestinoSrc.SelectedValue.Equals("Silo"))
                uas = constroiModeloEBusca(TipoUnidadeArmazenamento.Silo);

            else if (ddlTipoUADestinoSrc.SelectedValue.Equals("Moega"))
                uas = constroiModeloEBusca(TipoUnidadeArmazenamento.Moega);


            ddlSiloDestinoSrc.DataSource = uas;
            ddlSiloDestinoSrc.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            this.LoadSiloDestino(uas);
        }
    }
```

Auxiliar methods:

```
    private void LoadSiloDestino(List<UnidadeArmazenamento> unidadesArmazenamento)
    {
            ddlSiloDestinoSrc.DataTextField = TypeExtensions.NomedaPropriedade<UnidadeArmazenamento>(p => p.NOME);
            ddlSiloDestinoSrc.DataValueField = TypeExtensions.NomedaPropriedade<UnidadeArmazenamento>(p => p.IDUNIDADEARMAZENAMENTO);

            ddlSiloDestinoSrc.DataSource = unidadesArmazenamento;

            ddlSiloDestinoSrc.DataBind();

            ddlSiloDestinoSrc.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Selecione o destino", string.Empty));
    }



    private ListItem[] tiposUnidadeArmazenamento()
    {
         return UIHelp.BuildDropDownListEnum<TipoUnidadeArmazenamento>("Selecione um tipo");
    }

    private List<UnidadeArmazenamento> constroiModeloEBusca(TipoUnidadeArmazenamento tipoUA)
    {
        return new UnidadeArmazenamentoBO().GetUnidadesArmazenamentoByModel(new UnidadeArmazenamento { TIPOUNIDADE = tipoUA, Unidade = this.LoggedUser.UnidadeActiva }, false);
    }
```

And this last method is call at initialize page

```
        private void LoadDropDownList()
        {
            UnidadeArmazenamentoBO siloBo = new UnidadeArmazenamentoBO();

            if (ddlTipoGrao.Items.Count == 0)
                ddlTipoGrao.Items.AddRange(UIHelp.BuildDropDownListEnum<Grao>("Selecione o Grão"));

            if (ddlSafra.Items.Count == 0)
                ddlSafra.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Selecione a safra", string.Empty));

            ddlSafra.DataBind();

            if (ddlTipoOrigem.Items.Count == 0)
                ddlTipoOrigem.Items.AddRange(UIHelp.BuildDropDownListEnum<TipoOrigemEnsilagem>("Selecione o tipo de Origem"));

            if (ddlTipoDestino.Items.Count == 0)
                ddlTipoDestino.Items.AddRange(this.tiposUnidadeArmazenamento());

            if (ddlSituacaoProduto.Items.Count == 0)
                ddlSituacaoProduto.Items.AddRange(UIHelp.BuildDropDownListEnum<EstadoDoGrao>("Selecione a Situação"));

            List<Equipamento> secadores = new EquipamentosBO().GetEquipamentosByUnidade(this.LoggedUser.UnidadeActiva.IDUNIDADE).FindAll(s => s.TIPO == TipoEquipamento.Secador && !s.MANUTENCAO);

            ddlSecador.DataSource = secadores;
            ddlSecadorSrc.DataSource = secadores;
            ddlSecadorSrc.DataBind();
            ddlSecador.DataBind();
            ddlSecador.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Selecione o secador", ""));
            ddlSecadorSrc.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Selecione o secador", ""));

            ddlSiloOrigemSrc.DataTextField = TypeExtensions.NomedaPropriedade<UnidadeArmazenamento>(p => p.NOME);
            ddlSiloOrigemSrc.DataValueField = TypeExtensions.NomedaPropriedade<UnidadeArmazenamento>(p => p.IDUNIDADEARMAZENAMENTO);

            ddlSiloDestinoSrc.DataTextField = TypeExtensions.NomedaPropriedade<UnidadeArmazenamento>(p => p.NOME);
            ddlSiloDestinoSrc.DataValueField = TypeExtensions.NomedaPropriedade<UnidadeArmazenamento>(p => p.IDUNIDADEARMAZENAMENTO);

            List<UnidadeArmazenamento> unidadesArmazenamento = siloBo.GetAllUnidadesArmazenamentoByUnidade(this.LoggedUser.UnidadeActiva.IDUNIDADE, false);

            ddlTipoUADestinoSrc.DataSource = this.tiposUnidadeArmazenamento();
            ddlTipoUADestinoSrc.DataBind();

            ddlTipoUAOrigemSrc.DataSource = this.tiposUnidadeArmazenamento();
            ddlTipoUAOrigemSrc.DataBind();

            ddlSiloOrigemSrc.DataSource = unidadesArmazenamento;
            ddlSiloOrigemSrc.DataBind();//utilizado para consultas
            ddlSiloOrigemSrc.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Selecione a origem", String.Empty));

            ddlSiloDestinoSrc.DataSource = unidadesArmazenamento.FindAll(s => s.TIPOUNIDADE == TipoUnidadeArmazenamento.Silo);
            ddlSiloDestinoSrc.DataBind();//utilizado para consultas
            ddlSiloDestinoSrc.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Selecione um silo", String.Empty));

            ddlSituacaoProduto.DataBind();
            ddlTipoGrao.DataBind();
            ddlTipoOrigem.DataBind();

            if (!this.RecordStatus.Equals(string.Empty))
            {
                ddlOrigem.DataTextField = TypeExtensions.NomedaPropriedade<UnidadeArmazenamento>(p => p.NOME);
                ddlOrigem.DataValueField = TypeExtensions.NomedaPropriedade<UnidadeArmazenamento>(p => p.IDUNIDADEARMAZENAMENTO);
                ddlOrigem.DataSource = siloBo.GetAllUnidadesArmazenamentoByUnidade(this.LoggedUser.UnidadeActiva.IDUNIDADE, false);
                ddlOrigem.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

Any help is usefull, because, i'm totally lost!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if your dropdown is rebinded and selected value is overwritten when post back is done.bind your dropdown in pageload with condition

```
If(!IsPostBack)
```